# Google Cloud SQL on Amazon Java Web Project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-sql

Is it possible to connect via an Amazon Java Web Project (AWS EC2) to an Google Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a public IP address for your Google Cloud SQL instance, and that should allow you to connect from EC2. Although the latency might be unacceptable depending on the distance between the client and the database.